# DBSCAN on high dense dataset. R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, dbscan

I've been recently studying DBSCAN with R for  transit research purposes, and I'm hoping if someone could help me with this particular dataset.

Summary of my dataset is described below.

```
      BTIME ATIME
1029  20001 21249
2944  24832 25687
6876  25231 26179
11120 20364 21259
11428 25550 26398
12447 24208 25172
```

What I am trying to do is to cluster these data using BTIME as x axis, ATIME as y axis. A pair of BTIME and ATIME represents the boarding time and arrival time of a subway passenger.

For more explanation, I will add the scatter plot of my **total data set**.

[image: Scatter plot of my data set]

However if I split my dataset in different smaller time periods, the scatter plot looks like this. **I would call this a sample dataset**.
[image: Scatter plot in larger scale.]

If I perform a DBSCAN clustering on the second image(sample data set), the clustering is performed as expected.
[image]

However it seems that DBSCAN cannot perform cluster on the total dataset with smaller scales. Maybe because the data is too dense.

So my question is,
****Is there a way I can perform clustering in the total dataset?**
What criteria should be used to separate the time scale of the data**

I think the total data set is highly dense, which was why I tried clustering on a sample time period.

**If I seperate my total data into smaller time scale, how would I choose the hyperparameters for each seperated dataset?** If I look at the data, the distribution of the data is similar both in the total dataset and the seperated sample dataset.

I would sincerely appreciate some advices.

Comment: Perhaps use a smaller `eps`? Also, please provide a snippet of your code along with minimal and [reproducible example(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/10802499). Use `dput()` for data and specify all non-base packages with `library()` calls.

Comment: What's compelling you to use DBSCAN for identifying clusters? Based on your total dataset, it would be the last algorithm I would use to identify interesting populations. What's your end goal?

Comment: Hi ! What do yoo do when you "split" your dataset ? And what does mean the intervals between your cluster ? The nights, for example ? If so, no need to use algorithms, just check the dates and hours ...